# How to get string representation of date in Luxon with specified timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

I need to display dates in my web application with PST timezone. It should not be dependent of the timezone of the user.

I tried the following code:

```
const dateTime = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-22T15:00:00.000Z');
dateTime.setZone("America/Los_Angeles");
console.log(dateTime.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL));
```

But anyway, it displays:

```
March 22, 2022, 4:00 PM GMT+1
```

How possible to get output in timezone defined?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

DateTimes are immutable in luxon, so the .setZone() call will not change your original dateTime variable, rather it will return a new value.

I'd suggest setting the zone in the [`.fromISO()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimefromiso) call:

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const dateTime = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-22T15:00:00.000Z', {
    zone: "America/Los_Angeles"
});
console.log(dateTime.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL));
console.log(dateTime.toISO());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Or you could call .setZone() on the result of the .fromISO() call:

```js
const { DateTime } = luxon;
const dateTime = DateTime.fromISO('2022-03-22T15:00:00.000Z').setZone(
    'America/Los_Angeles'
);
console.log(dateTime.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL));
console.log(dateTime.toISO());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-Nw0Abk+Ywwk5FzYTxtB70/xJRiCI0S2ORbXI3VBlFpKJ44LM6cW2WxIIolyKEOxOuMI90GIfXdlZRJepu7cczA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for so complete answer!!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!